# Is there a LaTeX editor that supports writing white on black?

Tags: editors, texworks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides)

Is there a good editor for that supports white writing on a black background?

I'm using TeXworks and really like it but it is the only feature I would like but don't have.

Comment: Any editor with support for themes (including most text editors for example) can do this. Is this question really tex-related?

Comment: http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=56&t=6921

Comment: Use `TeXMaker` and `texstudio' from `http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/`.

Comment: Try vim with a terminal set to white text on black background.

Comment: Instead of more answers asking about specific features of editors, we should add to our big question the way I just did in the answer for Texmaker: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/402/4012. You might want to put a small bounty on the question in order to encourage such edits.